# Using CSS Transition when contents of a div are changed by React Script

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I use a state to render different components in a div hence changing its height. I want my css height transition to execute when the change happens. Please someone assist me with this.

React Code:

```
<div className="venue-details">
            {venue ? 
                <>
                    <span>Date: &nbsp;To Be Announced... </span><br />
                    <span>Location: &nbsp; My Location</span><br />
                </>:
                <>
                    <span>Click to view</span>
                </>
            }
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.venue-details{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-right: 10%;
    transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ReactTransitionGroup to animate the height of your div element:

```
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';
    // ...
    
    <CSSTransition
      in={venue}
      timeout={1000}
      classNames="venue-details"
    >
      <div className="venue-details">
        {venue ? (
          <>
            <span>Date: &nbsp;To Be Announced... </span><br />
            <span>Location: &nbsp; My Location</span><br />
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <span>Click to view</span>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </CSSTransition>
```

css:

```
.venue-details-enter {
  height: 0;
}

.venue-details-enter-active {
  height: [desired-height];
  transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
}

.venue-details-exit {
  height: [desired-height];
}

.venue-details-exit-active {
  height: 0;
  transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're adding/removing your spans to/from the dom, not changing the classes on them. Try something more like this:

```
<div className={venueDisplayClass} >
   <p className="withVenue">
        Date: TBA
   </p>
   <p className="withVenue">Location: TBA</p>
   <button className="withoutVenue" onClick={setVenueDisplayClass('showVenue')}>Click to View</button>
</div>
```

And then your css can be more like

```
.showVenue .withVenue {
   height: auto;
   transition: /* your transition */
}
.showVenue .withoutVenue {
  height: 0;
  transition: /* your transition */
}

.hideVenue .withVenue {
   height: 0;
}

.hideVenue .withoutVenue {
   height: auto;
}
```